# $http is undefined in service despite injecting it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a service to provide a js api for the integration between my angular app and the server it talks to. However, whenever I try to use $http in the service it is undefined.

The service is instantiated as $scope.broker in my main controller:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.broker = new broker();

...

angular
.module('inspinia')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http',MainCtrl])
```

The service is then used in a controller attached to the same module:

```
function locations($scope, $http){

console.log($scope.broker.ping);
$scope.broker.ping();

angular.module('sentry.locations', [])
.controller('locations', ['$scope','$http', locations]);
```

Service Definition:

```
function broker($http) {

    var baseurl = 'localhost:8000';

    var broker = {};

    broker.ping = function() {
        console.log(this);
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseurl + '/hello'
        })
    };

    console.log($http);

    return broker;
};

angular.module('inspinia')
    .factory('broker', ['$http', broker]);
```

console.log($scope.broker.ping) correctly prints the ping function.
console.log($http) prints undefined

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Added MainCtrl registration after elipses

Comment: lots of disconnects here. `broker` service isn't injected in controller so it should be throwing error. Also you have different module names, are these modules all in some dependency in main app?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using oc.lazyLoad so sentry.locations is loaded using that. Inspinia is the main application module. Adding 'angular.module('inspinia')
    .factory('broker', ['$http', broker]);' made it stop throwing errors for the broker service being undefined, so I assume that is doing the injection.

Comment: suggest you learn how to use angular without oc.lazyLoad first. I doubt your app is big enough to really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.broker = new broker();`

your broker is from `new` function in your `MainCtrl`,not injected by angular service,so `$http` is undefined.

Comment: So the thing I missed was that services had to be injected into controllers as well as registered with the module. I was not getting more useful errors because the constructor had the same name as the service and was in the global scope. Thanks to both cyrus zhou and @charlietfl for their help.